# TP-LINK EAP245 AP Configuration

Tags: wireless-access-point

I successfully configured the access point to my home network. The only trouble is that devices have to login into the AP to get internet access. I wanted to add AP to act as a range extension where devices (like cell phones and tablets) would have a passive handshake to the nearest AP without needing to login.

Is it possible to configure the APs so that the only login needed is for the router? If so, how do I set that up (what am I looking up to understand the configuration?

Comment: is the SSID for the AP the same as for the router? is the Password the same?

Comment: They are now.  Haha. Is that all it takes?

Comment: most of the time, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is required for a passive handshake on an access-point is the the *SSID* (Network name) and the password.

Both have to be the same on the router and the AP!

Comment: The AP fix worked for my phone (Samsung S9+), but my wife's iPhone is having trouble accessing the internet. I have to disconnect her from the network and reconnect to get it to work. Is there something I can change to get her connection to stabilize?